# This account can't be connected using Exchange Active Sync

Tags: windows, windows-8, activesync

I get the above error message when I try to add my google account to Windows 8 mail app. However I had previously activated Active Sync and its working on my windows phone. I get the error when I enter Server Address as m.google.com.

Comment: Are you 100% positive you had already activated the EAS because Google discontinued EAS support over 2 years ago.

Comment: @Ramhound am using it in Windows phone now. it works and also syncs google calendars.

Comment: I am almost 100% positive its per device besides Windows Phone address the underline problem with Google's decision to not support EAS in one of Windows Phone 8's updates.  Windows Phone 8.1 will include that change clearly.

Answer (score 0):

This is correct behavior.

Google discontinued EAS support for free (Gmail) accounts around January 2013 (July for Windows Phone 8). If your device did not already have EAS configured before that cutoff date, then google will refuse to set up EAS. It sounds like your Windows Phone was already set up, but your desktop was not:

> ### Google Sync End of Life
>
> Google Sync was designed to allow access to Gmail, Google Calendar, and Contacts via the Microsoft® Exchange ActiveSync® protocol. With the recent launch of CardDAV, Google now offers similar access via IMAP, CalDAV, and CardDAV, making it possible to build a seamless sync experience using open protocols. Starting January 30, 2013, consumers won't be able to set up new devices using Google Sync, however, existing Google Sync connections will continue to function. Google Sync will continue to be fully supported for Google Apps for Business, Government and Education users who are unaffected by this announcement.

If you want to set up a new device with EAS, you must be linking it to a Google Apps for Business/Education account.

Currently, Windows 8 provides IMAP support in the Mail application, but there is no way to do 2-way syncing of calendars or contacts because neither CalDAV and CardDAV are supported by the Calendar or People applications.

Google Apps for Business is $5/month/user, so I ended up just setting up that for myself on my personal domain with me as the only user and migrating to it.

---

On top of this, I think Microsoft added a block in Windows 8.1 that prevents adding `m.google.com` as an EAS server, which sounds like the error message you are running into. I'm still trying to find a way around this.

Comment: but even today i can delete my Active sync account from windows phone and add it again. its windows that's blocking. the request is not going to server. I don't agree. there is just one active sync or EAS. if its working for windows phone then it should work for windows mail app also.

Comment: That's correct - Your phone's ID is registered and approved with Gmail. Your Windows Mail app has a *different* ID, and unless you're either using *Google Apps for Business/Education* or you *configured Windows Mail before the cutoff date in January 2013*, Google will refuse to sync with it. I also added a bit to the answer about Windows possibly blocking `m.google.com`.

Comment: surely do let me know if you got a work around for m.google.com

Answer (score 0):

Use m.google.com:443 as the server to bypass that message. We are a Google apps for education institution, so new EAS connections are still supported for us. This behavior is obnoxious, as there are still many (corporate, government, and education) users who can use EAS with Google Apps.